# Map the column value against same sequences in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a query as per below input and output

Input :-

```
Num    Sr_no     Exp_no
NULL    1         1
NULL    2         1
ABC_1   3         1
NULL    4         1
NULL    1         2
NULL    2         2
ABC_2   3         2
NULL    4         4
```

Expected Output:-

```
Num    Sr_no     Exp_no
ABC_1    1         1
ABC_1    2         1
ABC_1    3         1
ABC_1    4         1
ABC_2    1         2
ABC_2    2         2
ABC_2    3         2
ABC_2    4         4
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit

Comment: Currently, I am getting data as per input but I want to write a query in a way that the expected output will be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no details in question, this answer is on below assumptions

1. you want to fill `num` field based on `exp_no` grouping.
2. Assuming there is only one value in a `exp_no` group.

Try this:

```
with cte as 
(
select distinct on (num,exp_no) num, exp_no 
from test 
where num is not null 
order by 1)

select 
coalesce(t1.num, cte.num),
t1.sr_no,
t1.exp_no 
from test t1 left join cte on t1.exp_no=cte.exp_no
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6565300319349be59bb6a171517801cf)

Comment: Thanx Sir..its works for me...and expected output is showing